# Two dependant uniform variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to solve an excercise that states:

> "A random number X is drawn at (0,1). Next, another random number Y
> with uniform distribution is drawn at (0, X). The probability that Y
> is greater than 0.5 is: (answer: 0.15)"

In theory I have two uniform distributed variables $X≈U(0, 1)$ and $Y≈(0, X)$ and I am given the conditional distribution: given $X=x$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $x$.

That is, for any $x\in(0,\,1)$ and any $y\in(0,\,x)$, the conditional density function of $Y$ should be
$f_{Y|X}(y\mid x)=\frac{1}{x}$ but i don't really know how to go on from here, since its conditionals, it seems like using the total law of probability would be a choice:

$P\left(Y\gt \tfrac12\right)=1 - P\left(Y\leq \tfrac12\right)=1 -\int_0^1 P\left(Y\leq \tfrac12\mid X=x\right)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx.$

$f_X(x)$ should be $1$ I think but I have no clue on how to calculate $P\left(Y\leq \tfrac12\mid X=x\right)$

Solutions are welcome if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: they said to you that $Y|X\sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,X)$, this means that

$$
\Pr [Y\leqslant c|X=x]=\begin{cases}
\frac{c}{x},& \text{ when }c\in(0,x)\\
1,&\text{ when }c\geqslant x\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Now observe that

$$
\Pr [Y>1/2]=1-\Pr [Y\leqslant 1/2]=1-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [Y\leqslant 1/2|X=x]P_X(dx)
$$

where $P_X$ is the distribution of $X$.